# What's the correct way to upload file in Puppeteer with Browserless (using workspace)?

Tags: puppeteer

I have an html form with an upload field, which I'm trying to use. I'm not sure if I'm going about this in the right way, any help would be much appreciated!

This first thing I did was to upload a PDF file to my Browserless endpoint:

```
0   
created "2023-05-26T05:01:13.635Z"
isDirectory false
name    "test_PDF.pdf"
path    "/workspace/test_PDF.pdf"
size    184575
workspaceId null
```

If I have understood the documenation correctly, I should now be able to use said file in chrome...

```
await page.goto('https://test.com/index.php');

// just type some random text in a input field
await page.type('input[type="text"]', 'browserless.io');

// get a handle on the input type file
const inputUploadHandle = await page.$('input[type=file]');

// can I just use the file like this, or must I add some path??
let fileToUpload = 'test_PDF.pdf';
inputUploadHandle.uploadFile(fileToUpload);

//submit the form
await Promise.all([
 page.click('input[type="submit"]'),
 page.waitForNavigation(),
]);
```

The submit does happen but no file is selected for upload...

I've tried multiple paths to the file but I'm not sure if this is the correct way ("test_PDF.pdf", "/usr/src/app/workspace/test_PDF.pdf", "/workspace/test_PDF.pdf").